# Populating json from multiple django models

Tags: python, django, filter, django-rest-framework, django-views

I have the following 2 Django models, `Lessons` and `UserLessons`.

`Lessons` would be created by an admin and `UserLessons` is basically when a user is in progress with the `Lesson` or `completed` the `Lesson`, linked by a foreign key. `UserLesson` doesn't necessarily contain a `Lesson` entry, till the user actually starts with that specific one.

As I'm building an API (with DRF), I need to list the full list of all Lessons - easy.
`LessonList = Lesson.objects.all().values('id', 'title')`

This returns

```
[
    {
        "id": 1,
        "title": "Lesson 1"
    },
    {
        "id": 2,
        "title": "Lesson 2"
    },
    {
        "id": 3,
        "title": "Lesson 3"
    }
]
```

However, I need to be able to merge it with UserLesson (eg `UserLessonList = UserLesson.objects.filter(user=request.user).values('id', 'lesson__id', 'completed')` which currently returns

```
[
    {
        "id": 2,
        "lesson__id": 1,
        "completed": true
    },
    {
        "id": 3,
        "lesson__id": 2,
        "completed": true
    }
]
```

Ideally, it should return all the lessons from the db, and the the completed values, defaulting to `completed: false` if that specific lesson doesn't exist in DB.

Any suggestions?

Edit:

Views

```
class LessonList(APIView):

    permission_classes = (IsAuthenticated,)

    def get(self, request):

        LessonList = Lesson.objects.all().values('id', 'title')
        UserLessonList = UserLesson.objects.filter(user=request.user).values('id', 'lesson__id', 'completed')





        return Response(LessonList)
```

Models

```
class Lesson(models.Model):
    author = models.ForeignKey(User, on_delete=models.CASCADE, null=True)
    title = models.CharField(max_length=250, verbose_name=u'Title')
    slug = models.SlugField(null=True, blank=True, help_text='eg, lesson-1-whats-up')
    published = models.BooleanField(default=False)

    def __str__(self):
        return(self.title)

class UserLesson(models.Model):
    user = models.ForeignKey(User, on_delete=models.CASCADE, null=True)
    lesson = models.ForeignKey(Lesson, on_delete=models.CASCADE, null=True)
    completed = models.BooleanField(default=False)

    def __str__(self):
        text = str(self.lesson.title)
        return(text)
```

Comment: Please add your code: serializers and viewsets

Comment: I don't have serialisers, but added the models and view.

Comment: But you wrote you building an API (with DRF). In this case how you use Django Rest Framework

Comment: I don't think that matters in this case.

Comment: It's really matter. Why you don't use serializers for solve this problem?

Comment: Can't you just get the data as a queryset regardless of DRF or not?

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/206582/discussion-between-ronald-langeveld-and-andrey-leontyev).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should use [ModelViewSet](https://www.django-rest-framework.org/api-guide/viewsets/#modelviewset) and serializers. Exactly [ModelSerializer](https://www.django-rest-framework.org/api-guide/serializers/#modelserializer). Something like this:

```py
class LessonSerializer(serializers.ModelSerializer):
    completed = serializers.SerializerMethodField()
    class Meta:
        model = Lesson
        fields = ['id', 'title', 'completed']

   def get_completed(self, obj):
        user = self.context.get('request').user
        return UserLesson.objects.filter(user=user, lesson=obj, completed=True).exists()

class LessonViewSet(viewsets.ModelViewSet):
    queryset = Lesson.objects.filter(published=True)
    serializer_class = LessonSerializer
    permission_classes = [IsAuthenticated]
```